# Can we make a client side ftp software like FileZilla in Adobe AIR?

Tags: flash, air, flexbuilder, flash-cs5

Hi All
Can we make a client side ftp software like FileZilla in Adobe AIR?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I believe somebody already developed a class for this:
http://maliboo.pl/projects/FlexFTP/